# How can I pre-emptively determine if accessing a property will cause an AccessViolation?

Tags: c#, process, access-violation, solidworks, vbe

I have a method in Rubberduck (an in-process VBE add-in) that is assigning a Picture and Mask to a `CommandBarControl`(Button). It works well when adding images to the VBE's of Excel, Word, etc., but it fails with an Access Violation when adding images to the SolidWorks VBE.

```
    public static void SetButtonImage(CommandBarButton button, Image image, Image mask)
    {
        button.FaceId = 0;
        if (image == null || mask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            button.Picture = AxHostConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(image);
            button.Mask = AxHostConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(mask);
        }
        catch (COMException exception)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Button image could not be set for button [" + button.Caption + "]\n" + exception);
        }
    }
```

I know from [**KB286460** - How To Set the Mask and Picture Properties for Office XP CommandBars](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286460)

> The Mask and Picture properties are defined as type IPictureDisp, which is a member of the Stdole library. IPictureDisp uses methods that cannot be marshalled across process boundaries. Therefore, the Mask and Picture properties can only be called in-process (VBA macros, **Automation Add-ins**, and ActiveX DLLs **run in-process**).

I know from [How to handle AccessViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469368/how-to-handle-accessviolationexception) that I *could* decorate the method with an `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute, but I don't think I want to carry on with a Corrupted State. Maybe *this* corrupted State is benign, and I can carry on?

Interestingly, Visual Studio's Autos window handles the `Picture` access exception without issue:
[image]

It seems that the SolidWorks VBE is somehow not treating/hosting Rubberduck as being in the same process as the CommandBarButtons. That suggests that other VBE hosts might do the same.

**EDIT I'm unsure if it is relevant, but I'm running an older version of SolidWorks 2006 under Windows 10, and in order to make it run, I have configured it to run with Administrative privileges.**

I *know* that accessing the `Picture`/`Mask` properties will cause an AccessViolation, but how can I determine if the property is readable/writable before actually trying to access it?

I *could* check if the host application is SolidWorks, but I'd rather a more generic approach that works for *any* host that has the same behavior.

Comment: Maybe this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243764/at-runtime-how-can-i-test-whether-a-property-is-readonly